# Trying to execute a module within a package downloaded from github gets error

Tags: python

When I try to run the main script file of a Python package, from Windows cmd prompt, I get Python errors.

I downloaded a folder from github, that contains a multi-folder Python package, to a folder zzz\ on my Windows 10 computer.  The package's top folder is OJWALCH_sleep_classifiers.

To run the package, I must run this module:
zzz\OJWALCH_sleep_classifiers\source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner.PY

I can't figure out how without error.

I opened a cmd prompt and did cd into zzz\OJWALCH_sleep_classifiers.

Here is what I've tried:

1st attempt...

```
At cmd line: python -m path and name of module
python -m source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner

ERROR:  
C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: No module named source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner
```

2nd attempt...

```
At cmd line:  python <path and name of module>.py
python 

python source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner.PY

ERROR:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner.PY", line 3, in <module>
    from source.analysis.figures.data_plot_builder import DataPlotBuilder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'
```

3rd attempt... CAN'T FIND MODULE: preprocessing_runner

```
At cmd line:  python <path and name of module>
python source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner

ERROR:  
(null): can't open file 'source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: The first one is wrong because when you specify a module name to Python, it should use `.` as a separator because you are giving it in Python syntax (not a Windows path to a file name). The second one is wrong because you started the Python program first and then tried to give a command-prompt command to that, instead of the command prompt. The third one is wrong because you omit the filename extension.

Comment: At any rate, this is really a question about how to use the computer, rather than a question about programming. I attempted to give a more detailed answer, but in the future you should ask (or search) instead on superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At cmd line: python -m path and name of module

This way, because you are giving the name *directly to Python*, you should use `.` between folder names, and no file name extension - because you are naming a *package and module*, not a path and file. So:

```
python -m source.preprocessing.preprocessing_runner
```

> At cmd line:  python .py

This would have worked, except that you tried to *start Python first*, and then give a command-line command *to Python*, instead of giving it to the command line.

> At cmd line:  python

Since this is a single command that *starts up* Python, we are giving it a path and file. So there should now be a .py extension:

```
python source\preprocessing\preprocessing_runner.py
```

We can also use forward slashes at the command prompt - it will break tab-completion, though.

Comment: Wow, I didn't have to fiddle with Python paths at.
I first cd'd into the top folder of my package then executed Karl wonderful solution.